# matlab importdata exception

Tags: matlab, file

I have saved my variable which is a 2D-matrix on a file named 'handwaving_78.table' and when I use importdata with this fileName I get this exception 
        `Error using VideoReader/read (line 145) Could not seek to frame.  Frame

    accurate seeking is not supported for this file on the current platform.

    Error in importdata (line 192)
    out = read(videoObj);

    Error in createNewDataSetFromReadFiles (line 28)

    data = importdata(strcat(baseClassFileAddress,'/',allFiles(j).name));`


I changed the name of my file to 'handwaving_78.txt' and everything worked fine.
I am using matlab R2014a on ubuntu 14.0.4 and want to know what is the problem because I do not want to change the file extensions.

Comment: For debugging purposes, could you run `[a,b,c]=finfo('handwaving_78.table');
d=VideoReader.getFileFormats;
d={d.Extension}` and tell me the content for the variables a to d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `importdata`:

> If importdata recognizes the file extension, it calls the MATLAB
>   helper function designed to import the associated file format (such as
>   load for MAT-files or xlsread for spreadsheets). Otherwise, importdata
>   interprets the file as a delimited ASCII file.

It's a mystery why `.table` files are recognized as videos, but there is little you can do to change this default behavior.

The solution I would propose is to use a more text-specific function like [`dlmread`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), [`readtable`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) or [`textscan`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) instead of `importdata`.

---

**Edit**

Another option would be to use the `'-ascii'` parameter with the `save` function (see [this link](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_fmt) for more related options):

```
save('some_address.table','data', '-ascii');
```

Then `importdata` should recognize your file as a text file.

Best,

Comment: I have checked and it turns out that when Matlab wants to read the 'handwaving_77.table' it calls finfo function and the answer is 'unkonwn'

Comment: However, when Matlab reads the 'handwaving_78.table' file it calls finfo function and the answer is 'video' so it tries to read it by VideoReader object.

Comment: Is there anyway to tell matlab the type of file when saving it?

Comment: save('some_address.table','data');

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem solved by using your method in saving the file in your edit.